# Angularjs : Remove old list item values from DOM

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to populate list items and further animate them using vTicker. My app.js makes a call to php which returns an object, which is then read by ng-repeat. The issue is, even after the object returns a new message, old message is still visible in html. However, if the page is refreshed, the old values gets cleared and only the latest message is displayed. How can I achieve this without having the page refreshed.

App.js :

```
   $scope.refreshbc = function () 
   {
        $scope.bclist = "";
        $http.get(bcurl).then(function(bcresponse) 
        {
            if(bcresponse.data.indexOf("Entry does not exist in    
            database") > -1)
            {
               $scope.bclist = "";
               console.log($scope.bclist);
            } else 
            {
              $scope.bclist = bcresponse.data;

              if($scope.bclist[0].msg == "No alerts.")
              {
                $scope.mibtn = "btn-success";
                $scope.mitxtcol = "black";

              } else 
              {

                $scope.mibtn = "btn-danger";
                $scope.mitxtcol = "white";
              }
           }

    });
```

$scope.refreshbc();
   $interval( function(){ $scope.refreshbc(); }, 30000);

html:

```
  <div id="example"  style="margin-top:39px;color:#cccc00;font- 
                                                   size:15px;">
    <ul  id="tickerul" style="list-style: none;">
      <li ng-init="stvticker()" ng-if="bclist[0].msg !== null" ng-
      repeat="bc in bclist track by $index" >{{bc.msg}}</li>
      <li style=""></li>
    </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting `$scope.bclist = "";` (a string) and then also treating it as an array of objects with properties (or at least a `msg` property)? If you are trying to clear the array you should use `$scope.bclist = [];`.

Comment: I made above change, but the list still displays old value. Page still needs to be refreshed to clear old value.

Comment: Weird. It should refresh when you change the array that is backing the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding below code in the function.

```
    $('#tickerul li').remove();
    $('#example ul').prepend('<li></li>');
```

Not sure if this is a good way to do it. :)